# Launch Openbox actions through script or cli

Tags: command-line, scripting, window-manager, openbox

I was wondering if it is possible to run openbox actions, like the ones that can be found on rc.xml like `MoveResizeTo` , through a console command so I can launch it from terminal or inside a bash script.
Or... is there such a thing like an openbox script? I tried to launch

`$ openbox UnmaximizeFull`

but it's not a valid argument

I tried to reach the same results through wmctrl or xdotool but I couldn't due a very specific issue that you can find at this link

[Deviation in wmctrl move command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576604/what-causes-the-deviation-in-the-wmctrl-window-move-command)

Comment: this feature is needed, i use xbindkeys as a universal tool for keyboard shortcuts and would love to use to execute openbox actions